# Отправка данных с формы на почту ajax+php

Tags: php, ajax

Здравствуйте, на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/93363/)

нашел статью как сделать отправку данных с формы на почту, у меня все работает, но после отправки происходит обновление страницы, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это убрать?(

Вот код Html

```
<div class="modal-order-form">
  <button class="modal-content-close" type="button" title="Закрыть"><span class="visibility-hidden">Закрыть</span></button>
  <div class="frame-form">
    <form id="modal-order-form" class="modal-form" method="post">
      <p>
        <label class="visibility-hidden" for="name-field-two">Ваше имя</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name-field-two" placeholder="Имя" required>
      </p>
      <p>
        <label class="visibility-hidden">Ваш телефон</label>
        <input type="tel" name="number" id="number-field-two" placeholder="+7-xxx-xxx-xx-xx" required pattern="\+7\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}">
      </p>
      <p>
        <label class="visibility-hidden">Ваш email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email-field-two" placeholder="Email">
      </p>
      <p class="modal-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="agreement" id="agreement-field" required checked>
        <label for="agreement-field"></label>
        даю согласие на обработку персональных данных
      </p>
      <p>
        <button  class="order-button modal-btn" type="submit">Отправить</button>
      </p>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вот js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#order-form").submit(function() {
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "send.php",
          data: form_data,
          success: function() {
            modalForm.classList.remove('modal-content-show');
            modalThx.classList.add('modal-content-show');
          }
        })
      })
    })
    </script>
```

И вот php

```
<?
if((isset($_POST['name'])&&$_POST['name']!="")&&(isset($_POST['number'])&&$_POST['number']!="")){ //Проверка отправилось ли наше поля name и не пустые ли они
        $to = 'example@mail.ru'; //Почта получателя, через запятую можно указать сколько угодно адресов
        $subject = 'Заказ с сайта'; //Загаловок сообщения
        $message = '
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <p>Имя: '.$_POST['name'].'</p>
                        <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['number'].'</p>
                        <p>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>
                    </body>
                </html>'; //Текст нащего сообщения можно использовать HTML теги
        $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; //Кодировка письма
        // $headers .= "From: Отправитель <@example.com>\r\n"; //Наименование и почта отправителя
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //Отправка письма с помощью функции mail
}
?>
```

Comment: `$("#order-form").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); ...`

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#order-form").submit(function() {

   //mnogo koda

   return false;
}
```

Или, например так:

```
<form id="modal-order-form" class="modal-form">

    //inputs,inputs,inputs

    <input type="button" value="Отправить" />
</form>

$(".order-button").click(function(){
    var form_data = $("#modal-order-form").serialize();
    $.ajax({ ...
       ...
})
```

Ещё так:

```
<form id="modal-order-form" class="modal-form" onsubmit="func_submin(this);return false;">
    ...
<button  class="order-button modal-btn" type="submit">Отправить</button>
</form>

function func_submin(frm){
    var form_data = frm.serialize()
    $.ajax({ ...
       ...;
}
```